# Laravel join multiple table with advance condition on first table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have several tables let say 3:

```
tblitem (100,000+ records)
tblcate (10 records)
tblcondition (10 records)
```

Now i want to select only 50 at once from tblitem. Here is what i want:

```
select *
from (select * from tblitem where enabled = true order by date desc limit 0, 50) t
inner join tblcate c on t.cateid = c.id
inner join tblcondition con on t.conid = con.id;
```

And in Laravel I wrote:

```
$result = DB::table('tblitem as t')->where('enabled', true)->orderBy('date', desc)->skip(0)->take(50)
      ->join('tblcate as c', 't.cateid', '=', 'c.id')
      ->join('tblcondition as con', 't.conid', '=', 'con.id');
```

But then I got this sql from Laravel:

```
select *
from tblitem t inner join tblcate c on t.cateid = c.id
inner join tblcondition con on t.conid = con.id
where t.enabled = true
order by t.date desc
limit 0, 50;
```

This make server join all records from the first table and then the query is slow.

How can I make it execute the first table condition first so that the record joining will be reduce and the query will be faster.

Thank you.